# Ldap authentication and ouath2 (access token and refresh token generation) integration in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, ldap, access-token

I have an existing Spring Boot application implementing Spring Security Oauth 2. Currently, using the inbuilt oauth2 authentication provider, i am able to get token details (access token and refresh token). I am able to get user details through UserDetailsService.

Now, i want to authenticate against the Ldap server and then generate the token details. But i am not sure how to modify the existing implemented oauth2 in spring security. Also, spring ldap doesn't generate tokens.

I am totally beginner in Spring. Any sort of help and guidance will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks